# How to pull a file through ADB?

Tags: android, adb

Actually in my application after an intent is sent I create a file called myfile.asc now i'm trying through ADB to pull that file but the issue is that by using

```
adb pull /data/data/xx.xxx.xxx/files/myfile.asc
```

or

```
adb pull /data/data/xx.xxx.xxx/files/myfile.asc C:\Users\me\Desktop\files
```

it returns

> "remote object does not exist"

The path is actually taken from the Android Studio device File Explorer by clicking on the file and copying the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the private folder file which is not accessible in non-rooted android device. For that you need to get the `adb shell` access then provide the permission to access that directory.

For this use case, I have created a library that can help you. It's open-sourced.

https://medium.com/@mohom.r/extracting-android-data-files-of-our-android-app-from-non-rooted-device-be9084ddbdc3

Comment: actually even by adding destination_path i get the same error..

Comment: Because you are trying to access the file which resides in the private directory where we don't have access until and unless you are using a rooted device. For this case you can try using the library : https://medium.com/@mohom.r/extracting-android-data-files-of-our-android-app-from-non-rooted-device-be9084ddbdc3

Comment: actually i can't use an external library as i'm writing a VB.NET programm that should work as a "syncronizer" and by sending some intent from ADB i create specific file and then i should pull that file.. If i will write the file in a external storage should i solve the problem?

Comment: Yes that would solve the problem. Writing the file to external storage.