# how to hide files in android (new proposed method)

Tags: android, file, adb, hide, termux

is it possible to hide files in android by transfering/moving them to a location or sector (like in root folders or something) of which other apps don't have access to (via adb or termux or something)?.

I have mentioned adb and termux because i've seen performing actions like uninstalling system apps from device. and if possible, i don't want to root my device.

One humble request: i don't know the ABC's of app building/compiling, maximum i can do is execute commands in adb/termux. so if you paste any code, please also mention what to do with it.

i have tried:
putting dot at starting of the name of the files is too older method and everyone knows about it. encryption and decryption is too much time consuming process. And i don't have that much important data, i just want to hide it from direct access so that most of the people can't find it by normal methods.

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull a file through ADB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891016/how-to-pull-a-file-through-adb)

Comment: @MorrisonChang It is near but not exact. instead of pushing or pulling a file, I want to move them within the android memory.

Comment: If you aren't rooted, on a real device, then a production (not debug) app's internal storage is inaccessible. Storage is already encrypted, see: https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption This question, with details as to what threat you are trying to prevent (steps to duplicate?), may be more appropriate on https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MorrisonChang i have android 11, which supports file-based encryption instead of full-disk encryption (according to my understanding of the documentation you have provided). there is implementation provided in this article with lots of command or program strings: https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/file-based

But i don't know how to implement or perform them.

Comment: All of the commands in that link are for building ROMs with security. Android 11 already has File Based Encryption turned on, from your link:`For new devices running Android 10 and higher, file-based encryption is required.`.

Comment: "so that most of the people can't find it..." it's your phone after all, who else will be able to access the files?

Comment: You want to hide files - so from whom or what? In general all apps have the same view on the system so hiding files from one app doesn't make sense. Each app has a private data folder only the app can access so there is no need fro an app to hide something, the app can simply use this private folder.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Can I encrypt my files manually by that provision? Thank you.

Comment: The whole FBE encryption system is transparent to Android once the device has booted up and the user has entered the PIN/password (if one is set). FBE is is designed to protect against offline attacks (Android is not running).

Comment: @Robert ok, understood. Thank you very much for giving me the info. So it is impossible to access root folders via ADB or to move files in them via ADB. I asked it because I wanted to perform that specific task for my specific requirement. I just don't want to make it look like my phone is locked for some reason.